# D3 Family Tree in angular

Tags: css, angular, d3.js, hierarchy, family-tree

I need to make an family tree in angular when I am using this function

```
renderFamilyTree() {
    // Set up the SVG container
    const svg = d3.select(this.familyTree.nativeElement).append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1200)
      .attr('height', 800)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)');

    // Create a tree layout
    const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([1000, 600]);

    // Create a hierarchy from the family data
    const root = d3.hierarchy(this.familyData, (d) => d.data);

    // Assign positions to each node
    treeLayout(root);

    // Draw nodes
    const nodes = svg.selectAll('.node')
      .data(root.descendants())
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

    nodes.append('circle')
      .attr('r', 10);

    nodes.append('text')
      .attr('dy', '.35em')
      .attr('y', (d) => (d.children ? -20 : 20))
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text((d) => `${d.data.first_name} ${d.data.last_name}`);

    // Draw lines connecting nodes
    svg.selectAll('.link')
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1)) // Exclude the root node
      .enter().append('line')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .attr('x1', (d) => d.x)
      .attr('y1', (d) => d.y)
      .attr('x2', (d) => d.parent.x)
      .attr('y2', (d) => d.parent.y);
  }
```

getting treee like this

[Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omSah.png)

now I want to connect node using the lines like this

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d50q.png)

I have tried with div also but not getting the expected output sharing the data I am using

```
this.familyData = {
      "family_id": "dd42d7c3-fe33-4cd9-83b2-b50721c45357",
      "family_name": "Schmeler family",
      "origin": null,
      "privacy": 1,
      "live_member_count": 3,
      "dead_member_count": 0,
      "city": "",
      "owner_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
      "data": [
        {
          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
          "first_name": "Alby's Father",
          "last_name": "Father",
          "gender": 1,
          "unique_code": null,
          "profile_pic": null,
          "marital_status": null,
          "living_status": 1,
          "friendRequest": null,
          "relation_type": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
              "first_name": "spouse 1",
              "last_name": "Father",
              "gender": 2,
              "unique_code": null,
              "profile_pic": null,
              "marital_status": null,
              "living_status": 1,
              "friendRequest": null,
              "relation_type": 1
            },
            {
              "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
              "first_name": "Abby's mother",
              "last_name": "none",
              "gender": 2,
              "unique_code": null,
              "profile_pic": null,
              "marital_status": null,
              "living_status": 1,
              "friendRequest": null,
              "relation_type": 1,
              "data": [
                {
                  "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                  "first_name": "Abby's sister",
                  "last_name": "none",
                  "gender": 2,
                  "unique_code": null,
                  "profile_pic": null,
                  "marital_status": null,
                  "living_status": 1,
                  "friendRequest": null,
                  "relation_type": 1
                },
                {
                  "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                  "first_name": "Alby",
                  "last_name": "none",
                  "gender": 1,
                  "unique_code": null,
                  "profile_pic": null,
                  "marital_status": null,
                  "living_status": 1,
                  "friendRequest": null,
                  "relation_type": 1,
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                      "first_name": "Alby's spouse 3",
                      "last_name": "none",
                      "gender": 1,
                      "unique_code": null,
                      "profile_pic": null,
                      "marital_status": null,
                      "living_status": 1,
                      "friendRequest": null,
                      "relation_type": 2
                    },
                    {
                      "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                      "first_name": "Alby's spouse 1",
                      "last_name": "none",
                      "gender": 1,
                      "unique_code": null,
                      "profile_pic": null,
                      "marital_status": null,
                      "living_status": 1,
                      "friendRequest": null,
                      "relation_type": 2,
                      "data": [
                        {
                          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                          "first_name": "Alby's child 1",
                          "last_name": "none",
                          "gender": 1,
                          "unique_code": null,
                          "profile_pic": null,
                          "marital_status": null,
                          "living_status": 1,
                          "friendRequest": null,
                          "relation_type": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                          "first_name": "Alby's child 1",
                          "last_name": "none",
                          "gender": 1,
                          "unique_code": null,
                          "profile_pic": null,
                          "marital_status": null,
                          "living_status": 1,
                          "friendRequest": null,
                          "relation_type": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                      "first_name": "Alby's spouse 2",
                      "last_name": "none",
                      "gender": 1,
                      "unique_code": null,
                      "profile_pic": null,
                      "marital_status": null,
                      "living_status": 1,
                      "friendRequest": null,
                      "relation_type": 2,
                      "data": [
                        {
                          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                          "first_name": "Alby's child 1",
                          "last_name": "none",
                          "gender": 1,
                          "unique_code": null,
                          "profile_pic": null,
                          "marital_status": null,
                          "living_status": 1,
                          "friendRequest": null,
                          "relation_type": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                          "first_name": "Alby's child 2",
                          "last_name": "none",
                          "gender": 1,
                          "unique_code": null,
                          "profile_pic": null,
                          "marital_status": null,
                          "living_status": 1,
                          "friendRequest": null,
                          "relation_type": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                          "first_name": "Alby's child 2",
                          "last_name": "none",
                          "gender": 1,
                          "unique_code": null,
                          "profile_pic": null,
                          "marital_status": null,
                          "living_status": 1,
                          "friendRequest": null,
                          "relation_type": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                  "first_name": "Abby's brother",
                  "last_name": "none",
                  "gender": 1,
                  "unique_code": null,
                  "profile_pic": null,
                  "marital_status": null,
                  "living_status": 1,
                  "friendRequest": null,
                  "relation_type": 1,
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "username": "Alby's brother spouse 1",
                      "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
                      "first_name": "Abby's brother 's spouse",
                      "last_name": "none",
                      "gender": 2,
                      "unique_code": null,
                      "profile_pic": null,
                      "marital_status": null,
                      "living_status": 1,
                      "friendRequest": null,
                      "relation_type": 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "user_id": "87d9dd1e-f34-1e3d-4e1d-9ecf-3ecd5e0c4526",
              "first_name": "spouse 1",
              "last_name": "Father",
              "gender": 2,
              "unique_code": null,
              "profile_pic": null,
              "marital_status": null,
              "living_status": 1,
              "friendRequest": null,
              "relation_type": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```